# Android Fix GPS to a single location

Tags: android, gps, location

I want to check if there are any apps that allow users to fix their GPS to a single location even though they are traveling.

Root/Unroot apps doest matter.

I have installed Xposed module but I couldn't find one app that does the function.

Thanks in advance.

P.s. I am on the application Fake GPS Location Spoofer. It works well when I am stationary. However, when I start to travel, it switches to and fro between real and spoofed location. I have tried making adjustments to my phone location settings to GPS only, and turning off WiFi mode.

That is the reason why I would want my GPS to be FIXED in a single location.

To the user who dont even read and understand my question:

Understand first before putting -1 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fake Location Spoofer Free is an app that I have used in the past.

Depending on your android version, you will have to "allow mock locations" in your developer settings, but I'm pretty sure the app will walk you through that.

[Fake Location Spoofer Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.incorporateapps.fakegps.fre&hl=en)

This app will allow you to fix your GPS to any location in the world.